# Is it possible to change the owner of a closure?

Tags: groovy

I have a static closure on Class A which delegates calls to Class B. However, when issuing a call() to the static closure on A with on a A instance i don't seem to have access to the instance properties on A. Not too suprising, as im working with a static closure. One way to solve this is ofc to set the instantiated A as the closures delegate. However, i need class B to be the delegate of the static closure.

Is there anyway i can change the owner of the static closure, so it points to the instantiated A class instead of the static? and keep B as the delegate? or is this impossible?

Comment: An example or two would really help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're wrong...  you can change the owner of a `Closure`, but how advisable it is, I don't know (as the setter is private, there must be a reason for this).  Anyway, here is an example:

```
// Define a Person, with a closure to return a property
class Person {
  String name
  int age
  Closure named = { -> "returned $name" }
}

// Define another Class with a similar property
class Furniture {
  String name
  int age
}

// Create our two objects
def tim = new Person( name:'tim', age:26 )
def chair = new Furniture( name:'chair', age:3 )

// Prints 'returned tim'
println tim.named()

// Add the closure from tim to the chair
chair.metaClass.named = tim.named
// Prints 'returned tim'
println chair.named()

// Change the owner to the chair instance
tim.named.@owner = chair
// prints 'returned chair'
println chair.named()
// prints 'returned chair'
println tim.named()
```

As you can see, we can change the owner from the Person class to the Furniture class.

In practice however, you probably want to be looking at setting the delegate for the closure rather than the owner, however with no examples of what you are trying to achieve, it is impossible to say whether this is what you wanted

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, however i solved my issue without having to take use of changing the owner of a closure. But, this is a great response for anyone else who wonders if it is possible to change the .owner property of a closure! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I found to override the owner is by re-declaring the instance of the closure:

```
    def myClosure = {  return this}

    def myOwnClass = new String('aa')
    assert myClosure.getClass().newInstance(myOwnClass,myOwnClass)() == myOwnClass
    assert myClosure.getClass().newInstance(myOwnClass,myOwnClass)() == 'aa'
```

Answer (score 0):

giving a (here simplified) real world example for the nice answer from [@tim_yates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5869484/1915920):

```
/** we want to use code completion and easy refactoring/debugging IDE capabilities
 * (without "manual String code parsing") when we refer to very static project
 * properties so working with them in a structured "enum-way" is useful */
@TypeChecked  enum ProjectId {

  foo( 'fooapp' )
  bar( 'app-bar', { idAnt = 'proj.bar' } )
  //bar( 'app-bar', { ProjectId it -> it.idAnt = 'proj.bar' } )  //(1)
  // ...
  ;

  // some static props of projects (may be many!)

  String id     // e.g. some standard repo name in a central dev store
  String idAnt  // e.g. some other id used in ANT scripts

  Class<BaseEnvId> envIdClass = EnvIdCommon  // default
  // ...

  /** the enum constructor */   
  ProjectId(  String _id,  Closure<Void> customizeDefaults = null  ) {
    id    = _id
    idAnt = id
    if ( customizeDefaults ) {

      // @owner-change so we do not have to use the clumsy/verbose syntax from (1)
      // (above and below) otherwise the runtime(!) compiler would complain that 
      // ProjectId.idAnt (static field) does not exist (which is right)

      customizeDefaults.@owner = this
      customizeDefaults()
      //customizeDefaults( this )  //(1)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's used for serialization, but it works.

```
Closure cloned = c.rehydrate(newDelegate, newOwner, newThis)
```

Answer (score -1):

And the answer is: it's impossible. One can't change the owner of a closure.

Comment: Not true: fooClosure.delegate = someOtherClass. Tim Yates is correct in requesting example code to demonstrate exactly what you are trying to do -- many different ways to achieve desired functionality in Groovy...

Comment: and what about `closure.@owner = otherInstance`...?  Probably not advisable (as I guess there is no `setOwner` method for a reason)

Comment: Thanks for the ".@owner =" tip.  For some reason (I loathe groovy and the groovy/geb project I have to maintain so I spent as little time understanding the cause as possible), when migrating code from one class to another, using ".delegate =" stopped working and I was having this be equal to the object where the closure was defined.  I tried ".@owner =" and everything started working again.  If I see one more ClassNotFoundException or MethodNotFoundException when I'm currently on a breakpoint in said class or method... arrgh!