# Use 'owner' property in Groovy DSL

Tags: groovy, dsl

Let's consider a simple Groovy DSL

```
execute {
    sendNotification owner
    sendNotification payee
}
```

The implementation of execute is

```
public static void execute(Closure dslCode) {
    Closure clonedCode = dslCode.clone()
    def dslDelegate = new MyDslDelegate(owner:  'IncCorp', payee: 'TheBoss')

    clonedCode.delegate = dslDelegate
    clonedCode.call()
}
```

and custom Delegate is

```
public static class MyDslDelegate {
    def owner
    def payee

    void sendNotification(to) {
        println "Notification sent to $to"
    }
}
```

The expected result of running `execute` block is

```
Notification sent to IncCorp
Notification sent to TheBoss
```

the actual one is

```
Notification sent to class package.OwnerClassName
Notification sent to TheBoss
```

The problem is `owner` is a reserved property in the Groovy `Closure` itself and no `resolveStrategy` options help to replace `owner` value with custom value from delegate due to Groovy `getProperty` implementation for `Closure`

```
public Object getProperty(final String property) {
    if ("delegate".equals(property)) {
        return getDelegate();
    } else if ("owner".equals(property)) {
        return getOwner();
    ...
    } else {
        switch(resolveStrategy) {
            case DELEGATE_FIRST:
        ...
    }
```

My question is how some one can outcome this limitation and use `owner` property name in a custom DSL?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a hack, but this should get you what you want, without altering Groovy source:

```
public static void execute(Closure dslCode) {
    Closure clonedCode = dslCode.clone()

    def dslDelegate = new MyDslDelegate(owner:  'IncCorp', payee: 'TheBoss')
    clonedCode.@owner = dslDelegate.owner
    clonedCode.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY

    clonedCode.delegate = dslDelegate
    clonedCode.call()
}
```

Ref:  [Is it possible to change the owner of a closure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844583/is-it-possible-to-change-the-owner-of-a-closure)

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, you can't. 'owner' is a reserved keyword in Groovy, and therefore by definition cannot be used as an arbitrary symbol. Even if there is a way to hack around this, you're far better off just using a name that doesn't conflict with the implementation of the language- this is especially true in Groovy, which keeps promising to redesign its MOP completely, meaning that any hack you implement may well stop working in future versions.

Perhaps the question would make more sense if you explained why you are willing to offer a bounty and search for a way of hacking around this problem, rather than just changing the name to something different and avoiding the problem entirely. Reserved symbols are a pretty fundamental limitation of a language, and ever attempting to work around them seems very unwise.